# How to get all children of a node in fancytree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, nodes, fancytree

I am trying to set a node's icon in fancytree. I found in online examples that I can use **renderNode** to do so:

```
 $("#tree").fancytree({
  // Image folder used for data.icon attribute.
  imagePath: "skin-custom/",
  // icon: false,
  renderNode: function(event, data) {
    // Optionally tweak data.node.span
    var node = data.node;
    // Some logic here
  }
});
```

I would like to go through the children of that node and if they are all selected, set an specific Icon. But when I get the children, I only get the first level children, meaning I don't get the node's children's children.
Is there any way to achieve that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `renderNode` callback is only called on demand, e.g. for new nodes, when a status changes, or when `node.renderStatus()` is called.

if you need to calculate icons you can use the [icon option](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#FancytreeOptions):

```
$(...).fancytree({
    icon: function(event, data) {
        return data.node.isSelected() ? "a" : "b";
    },
    ...
});
```

You can use this pattern to iterate over all nodes:

```
node.visit(function(n){
    console.log(n.isSelected());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will check the icon option for sure. I already have been using the `node.visit(function(n){
    console.log(n.isSelected());
});`  function.  But it doesn't iterate through all nodes. It only iterates the root and the first level children. I won't return The root's children's children. But Still thanks a lot :)

Comment: The visit method will traverse **all** descendants (except for unloaded lazy nodes of course)